# Optimization problem in KKT $(x_{1}-1)^2+(x_{2}-2)^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given an optimization as follows:
\begin{align}
    \text{minimize}\quad (x_{1}-1)^2+(x_{2}-2)^2 \\
    \text{subject to}\quad (x_{1}-1)^2 = 5x_{2} \quad \\
\end{align}

Guys I'm new here, I'm with this problem that I can not solve.

My resolution

**Lagrangian**

$L(x_{1},x_{2}, \lambda ) = (x_{1}-1)^2+(x_{2}-2)^2+\lambda(x_{1}^2-2x_{1}-5x_{2}+1)$

$\frac{\partial L }{\partial x_{1}} = 2\left(x_1-1\right) + 2\lambda x_{1} - 2 \lambda = 0$

$\frac{\partial L }{\partial x_{2}} = 2\left(x_2-2\right)-5\lambda = 0$

$\frac{\partial L }{\partial \lambda} = x_{1}^2-2x_{1}-5x_{2}+1 = 0$

$\lambda = \frac{2\left(x_2-2\right)}{5}$

How do I find the optimal solution? I don't know what to do

Comment: You need to compute $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}$ and set it equal to 0. Then you have 3 equations in 3 unknowns, its all algebra from there

Comment: I believe there might be a missing positivity constraint. At least on $x_2$.

Comment: In your case, you skipped ahead and found a way to express $\lambda$ in terms of $x_2$, so now you can substitute that back into ONE of the two equations $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} $ or $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}$, and then combine that with the constraint equation to get all solutions

Comment: An alternative to KKT is to substitute $(x_1-1)^2=5x_2$ in the objective function. Warning: this results in $x_2^*=-1/2$ and there are no $x_1$ that satisfy  $(x_1-1)^2=-5/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So our two equations you found combined imply that

$$ \lambda = \frac{2(x_2 -2)}{5} $$

[I didn't check this and will just assume you did the algebra correctly].

So now what to do with this information? We need to go ahead and grab one of your unused original equations. I will select

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1} = 0 \rightarrow (2 x_2 - 2) - 5 \lambda = 0$$

And we need to recall the third equation you forgot

$$ \frac{\partial  L}{\partial \lambda } = 0 $$

This of course just gives

$$ (x_1 - 1)^2 - 5x_2 = 0 $$

Which you might recognize as the original constraint. (The derivative w.r.t the lagrange parameter always gives the constraint)

So now we have our three equations

$$ \lambda = \frac{2(x_2 - 2)}{5} $$
$$ 2(x_1 - 1) +  2\lambda (x_1 - 1) = 0 $$
$$ (x_1 - 1)^2 - 5x_2 = 0 $$

We eliminate the $\lambda$ term.

$$ 2(x_1 - 1)  - 2(x_1 - 1) \frac{2(x_2 - 2)}{5} = 0$$
$$ (x_1 -1)^2 - 5x_2 = 0$$

And now we can solve this system of two equations in two unknowns but observe carefully a little earlier:

$$ 2(x_1 - 1) +  2\lambda (x_1 - 1) = 0 $$

Implies

$$ 2(x_1 - 1)(1 + \lambda) = 0 $$

So this simplifies your work considerably see @subrosar's answer for how that works/how to observe that trick even earlier in the problem.

Comment: Thank you @frogeyedpeas!

Comment: You should accept one of these answers if you found them helpful. Doesn’t have to be mine, but don’t leave all of us hanging. Use the check mark to the left of the answer to accept.

Answer (score 1):

The first partial of the Lagrangian simplifies to $2(x_1-1)(1+\lambda),$ so either $x_1=1$ or $\lambda=-1.$ If $x_1=1$ then the constraint tells us $x_2=0.$ If $\lambda=-1$ then the constraint on the second partial tells us $x_2=-\frac{1}{2}.$

Comment: If $\lambda = -1$ then $x_2 = -\frac12$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thank you @subrosar!

Answer (score 0):

Steps required:

Substitute $ x_2-2 = \frac52\lambda $ into $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}$, you get a linear equation only in $\lambda$. Hence you can solve for $\lambda$.

After you get $\lambda$, you can solve for $x_1$ using $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}$.

Now you can use the constraint to fidn the value of $x_2$.